# Python 2.x.x how to add a comma in print statement of python without preceding space character?

Tags: python

I am new to python and learning,

Code:

```
name = "Andrew"
print name,","
```

Output:

> Andrew ,

A space character is injected in before the comma, which is undesirable. How may we print the comma immediately after name like `Andrew,`  with no intervening space character?

Comment: This is the wrong forum: read the text of your tag.

Comment: Please ask in stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behavior of the `print` command of Python is to add a space between its arguments.

In Python 2.x.x:

You could use the string concatenation operator `+` to do this before you `print` it like:

```
name = "Andrew"
print name + ","
```

Output:

> Andrew,

However, if you are dealing with Python 3.x.x you could use the argument `sep` to change the separator from space to empty character like:

```
print(name, ",", sep="")
```

Comment: @Stephen. I did not get the implication you are indicating from reading the answer.